# Problems by updating

Tags: software-installation, update-manager, disk-usage

When trying to run the automatic update I get as alarm that " Your boot sector is full" try to delete you trash or/and run: sudo apt-get clean in your bootsector .

I've tried but it doesn`t help - bootsector is about 245MB large on Ubuntu 14.04 and 500 Gb HD

Comment: edit and include the output of `uname -r` and `sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*' `

Answer (score 1):

You should try to remove the old kernels, i.e. the packages named linux-image-xxxxx-generic, where xxxxx is any old version that you are not using. In order to see which version you're using you can run:

```
uname -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot).

If that doesn't help, could you please show us what files are at`/boot`?

Answer (score 0):

vmlinuz are found in a number of 6 - from 23 and upward to 30.

so due to an anserw it should be to delite  nr 2323,24,25 and 26. there is som **.efi to.

So i stared whith nr 23.

terminal:
sodu apt-get purge linuz-3.16.0-23-generic   and enter o c.

result:command not found    ???????? by all means i have seen som odd signs like a parashute in 90degress turn but that i have not seen on my keebord.

Obviusly i am doing somthing wrong - BUT WHAT??

Comment: Ok, please stay calm and use proper grammar.

Please copy the output of `ls /boot` from a terminal.

Comment: What you are trying to do is correct, but please keep in mind that linux does exactly what you ask it to do.
You should remove all of those packages but the latest kernel, which in your case seems to be linux-3.16.0-30-generic. 

If you misspelled `sudo` like you did above, the command will not work. Please check your commands for spelling errors.

Comment: And you was absolutly right!!!!I have been figthing those damned letters for 60 years and they still dont works as i will!

Comment: If your problem is resolved now, please mark the solution that helped you so other users with the same problem don't have to ask again.